# How can I test a hex Schmitt trigger?

Tags: test, schmitt-trigger

Yay, me...I just got done soldering my first surface mount IC. Because I know how volatile heat can be, and with how close the tip of my iron was to the IC (especially without a socket!), I'd like to make sure I didn't inadvertently fry the IC.

Other than testing the continuity between in/outs, what are some ways to test the other pins on a breadboard before I wire the board into my project?

Comment: Which IC chip is it? The particular logic family could help to narrow down the types of issues to look for. Such as the differences between 74LS04 (hex inverter) and a CD4009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply a logic level to each of the inputs, and see what the outputs give. If they're inverters the output should be 0 V when you apply 5 V (or whatever your supply voltage is) to then input. Connect the input to ground and you should get 5 V out.

It's unlikely that you fry it through the heat of soldering. ICs withstand temperatures of 300 °C *on all pins simultaneously* for several seconds. ESD may be another issue.

Answer (score 3):

Even though if each gate in the chip gives you the correct output for a steady-state logic input, an important property of [schmitt  triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) that must be tested are the thresholds of its hysteresis loop.

[image: hysteresis loop]

To accurately do that, you need an oscilloscope and a signal generator though. You need to feed it with a sine-wave signal (with peaks at logic 0 and 1 voltages) and check the resulting square-wave output. State transitions of the output should happen within the limits of acceptable threshold in the datasheet.

Without a scope and signal generator, you can still check if it is functional (no guarantee on the thresholds) by forming a relaxation oscillator. Please see this [link](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/generators.html).

[image: schmitt trigger relaxation oscillator]

A functional gate should give you a square-wave output. Choose an RC combination to give a comfortably low frequency so you can check the output without a scope: either driving an LED (blinking, [less than 15Hz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold)) or connected (decoupled by a capacitor) to a speaker (buzzing/thumping, [between 60Hz to 18KHz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range)).