# Automatic on and off bulb using CAPACITOR

Tags: capacitor

Automatic ON and OFF BULB for specific time only.

Following are considered to achieve the project...

1. As 12 v is supplied, relay R1 is slowly activated and bulb B1 will glow for specific time T which is dependent on capacitor C. As C is fully charged after sometime, say 5v, it blocks current and hence B1 is off.
2. In the meantime, R2 is always activated as long as 12v is supplied. Now, as 12v is disconnected, the energy stored in capacitor C is discharged through 87a of relay R2 and B2 now glows for specific time T again.
3. In short, B1 glows for time T and off when capacitor C is full, and B2 glows for time T only when 12v source is disconnected.

Would like to hear any comments or suggestions to rectify my project in achieving the on and off bulb for specific time only. Thanks.[image]

Comment: A quick google search gives, among many, https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/make-a-simple-capacitor-transistor-timing-circuit

Comment: What time are you hoping to achieve? 

If it's more than a few mS, likely not long enough for the relay to fully close, this this is an incorrect approach.  

Why?  The time-constant of the circuit with the capacitor, which determines how long current will flow, is going to be quite LOW since the R (resistance) of the relay coil is low compared to the C (capacitance) value of the capacitor.  There are much better ways to do this, perhaps using a 555 timer (or similar) IC.

Comment: 3 to 5 minutes of time..

Comment: 3-5 minutes of delay is NOT achievable with any practical C value that I can imagine using this circuit.  Again, I think your best bet is a simple 555 timer circuit which can easily achieve 3-5 minutes with readily available components.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html

Comment: Sir, could you please kindly provide the sketch diagram using 555 timer??

Comment: Sir, the project primarily is for auto lock and unlock car doors. The voltage is to be generated with DC dynamo attached to the wheels. As the wheels rotate faster, current will be produced which in short time charge the capacitor and auto lock the doors, and as soon as engine is off, it will automatically unlock the car doors.

Comment: Why have you got a different description of the requirements in the comments to that in the original question?

Comment: If you have a dynamo running off the wheels and your circuit works as you want, the doors will lock when the car reaches a speed where enough current is generated to power the relay.  The doors will then unlock when the car slows down for a junction, as you speed up the doors will lock again.  However the way you have used the capacitor will mean it won’t work at all.  You likely need a microcontroller monitoring the speed of the car and the ignition switch.

Comment: Sir, could you help which microcontroller best suited for my project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just about any microcontroller is capable of doing what you want.  An arduino would likely be an easy on to get started with.

Comment: Your question says you want the relay on for a certain time. Your comments make it clear that you want the relay on when the speed is above a certain threshold and this is independent of time unless all your car journeys are the same length. Are you really attaching a dynamo to the wheels of a car? How? Hit the edit link below your question and fix it up ...

Comment: @ThangTons: You have provided a diagram which, sorry to say to, will not work at all. Several suggestions have made to help you but you keep asking for a complete system/solution. Please realise that this is not a free design
house or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied
out to you on demand.Why don't you take the suggestions and from that come up with a better, more feasible diagram. We will then be happy to look at it again.

Comment: There are simpler ways with 74HC14 NPN transistor and switch ground side relay coil to 2 lamps from SPDT 12V 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37606/how-can-i-test-a-hex-schmitt-trigger

Comment: A word of warning: I've had issues with 555 timer circuits in car electronics.  The voltage drop during cranking can cause undesirable effects

Comment: @ChrisH Surely that will be the fault of your power supply design rather than a problem with the 555.

Comment: @HandyHowie more, my *lack of a* power supply design, as everything I was using was rated to 16V or higher.  I took it out with the intention of rebuilding at 5V with a regulator and never put it back in